# Can I throw a message fault back to a WCF client from a routing service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, encryption

My company has long used ASPX and windows services through a routing program to manage the connections and allow our datacenters to control where the clients make connections.

Just recently we started using MVC and WCF. Yes in 2015 we are just moving to these things. Anyway they figured out about a month before release they need to route the WCF traffic because of where it sits outside the firewall or in the DMZ.

We will be putting the routing service inside the network and opening a port on a firewall that way all services can communicate protected by the firewall on the routing service.

The only reason I have given all these details is because this sets up the expectations for how our WCF service is configured. We are using certificates for security and message encryption as we must send our messages encrypted. We are also adding a custom header that our router will use to route the messages.

What we have working is our router receives the message, inspects the header, finds if we have an endpoint, forwards the message, gets the response and sends it back to the WCF service. Currently that is all working beautifully. We can even receive the messagefault from the endpoint and send it back to the client.

What I am struggling with is how the router can send a messageFault back to the client when the fault originates in the router. But because my router doesn't know how to encrypt the message this fault is being sent back unencrypted. The faults beings things like "endpoint unreachable" or "no endpoint found". The client receives these faults with the error:

```
An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. 
See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
```

With the inner exception being what I defined in my code below.

```
Dim fe As FaultException = New FaultException(status)
Dim fault As MessageFault = fe.CreateMessageFault()
Dim msg = System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(getMessageVersion, fault, getAction)
```

getMessageVersion will return Soap11 or Soap12 depending on the client 
getAction is returning the action from the client request in the header.

Is there a way to configure the clients to accept these faults even though they aren't encrypted? We would like to catch them as Fault Exceptions not as Exceptions to keep our Fault Exception logic together for general Faults.

Any help or insight would be appreciated. Our newer programs are using C# our older ones are still written in VB, so throw whatever .Net code at me you are comfortable with and I'll use it.

Comment: Just a couple of questions to better understand your scenario:
1) are you using Wcf Routing or implementing a custom routing, like a method that receive a Message object?
2) does your your client know the custom fault class you are throwing or the operation are marked with FaultContractAttribute in the interface of your routing application?

Comment: The service is that is doing the routing is actually just a windows service with a HTTP listener. The hope was we could route all traffic through the same system so we wouldn't have to create new endpoints still using the same routing service. 

2) We are just throwing a general fault. The router will most likely end up having about 50+ WCF services using it, we have talked about creating a Fault to share with the clients, but it was decided currently that we will just have the router throw a Generic Fault. Handled by  catch (FaultException ex)

Comment: Interesting, we have a similar solution here.
We just could correctly send Fault to client when we created a class, with DataContract attribute, a single string property for Message. Them, in the operation of service, we decorated with FaultContract.
So, when any exception happens, we create an object of FaultException<CustomFault> and it serializes perfect to clients.
If you want, I can provide a sample code.

Comment: I would be interested in taking a look at a possible solution for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ricardo's information I was able to narrow down what I was doing. The actual answer to this is entirely up to the Endpoint configuration. It is dependent on your binding.

We didn't have to change any thing in the router, but we had to change the client it looks like this.

```
    serviceClient.Endpoint.Binding = getWSHttpBinding();
```

Then it should be

```
    private CustomBinding getWSHttpBinding()
    {
        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = (1024 * 1024 * 10);
        BindingElementCollection elements = binding.CreateBindingElements();
        elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;

        return new CustomBinding(elements);
    }
```

this link has further information if you see this problem. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971493

We will probably just handle this as an exception rather than a fault.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the Fault class:

```
    [Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "yourNamespace")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "yourNamespace")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace = "yourNamespace")]
public class CustomFault : ISerializable
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the interface and operating method referencing the Fault:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "yourNamespace")]
public interface IService
{
    [FaultContractAttribute(
        typeof(CustomFault),
        Action = "", 
        Name = "Fault", 
        Namespace = "yourNamespace")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults = true)]
    [OperationContract]
    Response Operation(Request request);
}
```

And finally how I throw the Fault:

```
throw new FaultException<CustomFault>
             (
                 new GuiaMedicoFault("Custom Error description"),
                 new FaultReason("Error description")
             );
```

Maybe some piece of this code can help you or give any ideas.

Comment: Are you using a custom endpoint or a WSHttpBinding? I am currently trying to use a WSHttpBinding and I think that might be the cause. It seems like I have to change a flag in my endpoint to accept my message.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971493

Comment: I use BasicHttpBinding and WebHttpBinding. Almost all services use Basic and some specific and rest services use WebHttp.
To make them all work with same operation, I decorated my service with these attributes:
[ServiceBehavior(ValidateMustUnderstand = false)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]